# What's the best Mind Mapping Software?

Tags: software-recommendation

Back in the dark days when I used to run windows I used to use MindJet Mindmanager and I found it to be very good. 
Since I have been using Ubuntu as my main operating system I have been trying to find a replacement mind map software to use but have not had any luck finding a good replacment. 
So far I have tried VYM, kdisset and Semantik. I have either found them not to be very good or have a nasty habit of crashing.

So I was wondering could anyone recommend good mind mapping software to use under Ubuntu?

Comment: very nice and informative post and their replies. http://www.mindmappingsite.com/sw-tool-reviews/software-reviews

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I like [FreeMind [image: Install freemind]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/freemind) very much, which is a Java mindmapping tool. Colleagues of me like [XMind](http://www.xmind.net/) most.

Comment: A small note on Freemind (which I too like): I couldn't get it to function with OpenJDK on a clean 10.04 install.  I had to remove all openjdk and icedtea packages and install the proprietary sun-java6-jre packages instead.  (Incidentally, I also had to do this to get the Firefox Zotero-to-OpenOffice plugin to work).

Comment: I will try at home and tell you.

Comment: Freemind does seem good is there a way to make it automatically balance the tree?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to auto-balance the tree. Concerning openjdk, I took a look at the start script. Maybe installing libgcj9-0-awt or libgcj10-awt is an option.

Comment: Freemind is working well with OpenJDK in the current state of the 11.04 development branch of Ubuntu.  So it should be working fine when 11.04 is released.

Answer (score 15):

[XMind](http://www.xmind.net/) has better graphics than [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/) but it's much heavier.

**Pro's include:**

1. Good customizable GUI.
2. Available for any major platform.
3. There's a portable version for the USB.

**Con's:**

1. It's java based. That makes it a bit slow.

Comment: I use Xmind free version too.

Comment: I started with freemind on Windows.  When I moved to Ubuntu I had trouble configuring it.  Then I tried Xmind and stuck with it.  It's multiplatmform too.  I use it with dropbox to sync maps between machines.

Comment: XMind 8 has serious performance issue - typing delay is few seconds (on each typed letter).

Answer (score 15):

Try using [Freeplane [image: Install freeplane]](https://snapcraft.io/freeplane-mindmapping).

Freeplane is a powerful and free software for building the mind maps. It is a redesigned version of the well known FreeMind, and is created by one of FreeMind's key developers. I prefer it over FreeMind since there are more options. Also, questions or problems with the program are answered and fixed MUCH faster.

Answer (score 5):

[Mindmeister](http://www.mindmeister.com) — online lightweight mind mapping tool.

Answer (score 3):

After browsing through the various options here, which mostly aren't in 16.04 repos I think, I tried [xournal](https://github.com/dmgerman/xournal), which I noticed Yann LeCun uses in his lectures.  It works pretty well.  I modified it slightly so its easier to autorecognize lines https://github.com/hughperkins/xournal/tree/easier-autolines

Comment: Edit: finally I use labyrinth.  Again, I hacked it a bit, to use a desktop load/save/new paradigm, rather than the mobile-paradigm in mainstream.  My hacked labyrinth https://github.com/hughperkins/labyrinth

Answer (score 3):

Minder is available as a flatpak in Pop!_OS, so it should work similarly in Ubuntu: https://github.com/phase1geo/Minder

It is styled after Elementary OS

These answers should be updated as many of these programs appear to be obsoleted. Here is a more current list: https://www.fossmint.com/free-mind-mapping-software-for-linux/ which does NOT include Minder for some reason (probably due to naming, it is difficult to search for "Minder mind mapping software" without a search auto-correcting you away from intended results due to assuming you had a typo or duplicate word)

Comment: Minder is a great modern tool, thanks for the tip!
Agreed. The answers should be updated to exclude obsolete/unmaintainted software.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try running MindJet MindManager under Wine.  Apparently some people have had [some success](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=7975&iTestingId=47830) doing so.  If all else fails, you could run a windows guest system on an  Ubuntu host via [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I started using VYM (View your Mind) http://www.insilmaril.de/vym/

Answer (score 1):

Another good one to try is Personal Brain, it has a free flow feel to it.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried Freemind and really didn't like it.
The one I liked the most on Ubuntu was [Semantik](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=55242), both for its ease of use and because [Semantik](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=55242) mind-maps are exportable to ODT as outlines.

One downside is that it's a KDE app so it wouldn't integrate with your desktop  well.

Comment: Semantik is hard to use.

Comment: I use KDE so i prefer a KDE-based app.

Answer (score 1):

It is VUE Visual Understanding Environment whic can be download from: https://vue.tufts.edu/download/index.cfm, I use it in Windows 7 & love it and having a Ubuntu version is an add to the software...

Answer (score 0):

Labyrinth is a lightweight mindmapping tool in the ubuntu repository. It's features are not much compared to freeplane. But it can do basic mind mapping.

Install it with `sudo apt install labyrinth`